# UISearchBar, NSPredicate and NSMutableArray

Tags: nsdictionary, uisearchbar, key-value

Have next Table View:

[image capture screen](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6217319/Shot.png)

this its make with two NSMutableArrays from Sqlite Database, sublista and subdetail, in example element 0 of sublista contain "A Barda" and element 0 of subdetail contain "Ponteceso".

This code generate this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"subCell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];




    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;

    }
    NSString *title;



        cell.textLabel.text=[sublista objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[subdetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Need Add A UIsearch bar and create NSDictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *playas = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:sublista, @"nombreplaya", subdetail, @"localidadplaya", nil];
```

But How implement Search or filter Here?

BEST REGARDS

Comment: try to look at the tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Comment: I try this, but the problem its that result one array filtered, and lost pairs with another array. THAT ITS THE PROBLEM!...